# I can not open and use a file that i have already made in Qt

Tags: qt

In my program i am trying to have several pages which i have handled by making several widgets.

in one of the pages i want to get an ID and username and password and store them in a file. which i can do without any problem.

but then in another .cpp file i want to use the information that is stored in those files to see whether the entered username and password are correct or not. but i can not open those files that i already made and read them.

So i would appreciate some help in how to open and use files that are already made and have text within them.

what I've already managed to write for storing the info is:

```
QFile users_file; // making a file
QString ID= ui->IDlineEdit->text(); // storing what is written in the LineEdit in a QString
QString username= ui->UserlineEdit->text(); 
QString password= ui->PasslineEdit->text();

users_file.setFileName(ID); //the file's name will be the ID
users_file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text);  
QTextStream users_fileStream(&users_file);  

    users_fileStream.operator <<(ID);
    users_fileStream.operator <<("\n");
    users_fileStream.operator <<(username);
    users_fileStream.operator <<("\n");
    users_fileStream.operator <<(password);
    users_fileStream.operator <<("\n");



//and this is what I've written for opening the files and reading them.
// but i have to mention that this part is in another .cpp different from the
// one that i wrote my previous code in it. 
// i know it doesn't work but that's all i could think of so far.

   int i=1;
   while( i)
    {

           QString username= ui->lineEdit->text();
           QFile myfile;
           myfile.setFileName(username);
           myfile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
           QTextStream files(&myfile);
           QString PassFromFile;

// I've written this part twice because the password is actually the second line on my file.
           PassFromFile=files.readLine();
           PassFromFile=files.readLine();

           if( PassFromFile == ui->lineEdit_2->text())
           {   i=0;
               this->centralWidget()->hide();
               usersPage->show();
           }

}
```

Comment: check the return value of open and myfile.errorString()

Comment: If there is no limitation for file format, I strongly advise you to use `QSettings`. It's very convenient for your task and can be used to store data in arbitrary INI files. "I've written this part twice" - this is horrible. You could just write `files.readLine();` without assigning.

Answer (score 0):

Try closing the file you've written to to make sure all data are flushed to the disk.

```
users_file.close();
```

Comment: I already have.
I missed it here when i was copy-pasting my code.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a really basic example of how to read from a file. Doing a quick google of "File IO and Qt" returned about a million examples and explanations of how to do these kind of things. Good luck.

```
QFile file("pathToSomeFile/someFile.txt");
if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    QMessageBox::information(0, "Error", file.errorString());

QTextStream in(&file);

while(!in.atEnd()) {
    QString line = in.readLine(); 
// Do whatever you want to do with this data here
// We're reading in one line of text from the file at a time  
}

file.close();
```